# How is jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar inter-connected during execution?

Tags: jsf, mojarra

I am trying to understand how the entire JSF specifications (jsf-api.jar) are converted to jsf-impl.jar (JSF Mojarra implementation). There are certain changes that I will have to do in the source code of JSF Mojarra to suite my needs. But when I am trying to do a change,the editor is throwing a lot of errors. I knew, I was missing the basic point of understanding how jsf specifications are implemented technically ? For example , if I try to implement a class of specifications explicitly, how do I link it to the entire implementation ?

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes no sense. It would be helpful if you tell a bit more about the errors which you got. They namely contain the whole answer at its own.

Answer (score 1):

The JSF API is the public API which is as published from the JSR. The implementation files are the basic implementation of the API. The files are generally loaded as services via a couple of different mechanisms like META-INF.services/ You should read the JSR for implementers if you want more details.